# Mathpix getting started authorization

Tags: git

I'm trying to work with Mathpix. On their docs it says to clone something from Git first. See their docs here: https://docs.mathpix.com/#introduction. When I try to clone through Git Bash typing `git clone git@github.com:Mathpix/api-examples.git` as the instructions say, I get the following response:

```
Cloning into 'api-examples'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Well, where can I put my API keys on Git Bash? The instructions say that the keys are placed in the following format:

> The request headers must be set as follows:
>
> ```
> {
>   "content-type": "application/json",
>   "app_id": "YOUR_APP_ID",
>   "app_key": "YOUR_APP_KEY"
> }
> ```

And this is through HTTP Basic Auth according to them.

So, as far as I see it, I can't put my keys on Git Bash when I clone because the keys are in JSON format, but then I can't clone and I'm stuck in the first step.

Comment: You have set up authentication for git to use against github, but this authentication is wrong. That's why it fails. You will have to fix your authentication settings for github by either clearing them out, which would then fall back to anonymous cloning, or you will need to add proper working authentication for github.

Comment: Thanks for your response Lasse. May I follow up and ask, how do I do that an which type of auth do I need for cloning? There seems to be so many options for github authentication from their site: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github

Comment: How to clear your authentication data can depend on the operating system.

Comment: I have Windows.

Comment: Open start menu and search for "Credential manager" by typing it out, then remove all entries for git under Windows Credentials.

Comment: I went to Windows Credentials but I didn't see any git entries there.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, the authorization is for the requests to the API. You will need this header then. To clone, I used:

```
git clone https://github.com/Mathpix/api-examples.git
```

This cloned the API Examples and you can then change directories using `cd api-examples/images`.

Comment: But what I'm saying is that it fails to clone because I don't know how to put the key in the cloning process.

Comment: You don't need the key to clone with this answer. Works for me.

Comment: But it doesn't work for me. Like I said, it tells me: Cloning into 'api-examples'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.